# What does the "black body" spectrum look like from a neutrom star?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, neutron-stars

In a recent discussion I learned that when neutron stars form they cool down much quicker than a black body of the same size and temperature because they can radiate neutrinos from their interior as well as photons from their surface.

I'm basically wondering how one sets up the calculation to compute the thermal spectrum from a black body that can radiate from it's interior as well as surface.

In the [normal case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#Derivation), one may proceeds roughly by determining the density of states of the photon modes and then use their Boltzmann weights to determine the thermodynamic partition function.

Does the procedure for radiation from the interior proceed in the same way as the calculation from the surface or are there important differences?

Comment: To begin with the density of states is strongly affected by the degenerate velocity distributions of the neutrons and electrons. In short it is not the spacial surface, but the Fermi-surfaces that glow.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. The neutron star surface radiates photons (very roughly) as a blackbody. The neutron star interior produces (very roughly) thermal neutrinos at about 100 times the temperature.

Comment: [Neutrino Emission from Neutron Stars](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0012122) .

Comment: I think your comment cleared up my confusion. Sorry if the question did not make sense, though. Basically what you are saying is that the neutrino radiates as a black body, it's just that the neutrinos are so much hooter than the surface of the neutron star.

Comment: If you are asking what is the neutrino energy spectrum, then the answer is not a blackbody. However, the spectrum and the total emissivity is temperature dependent and the characteristic temperatures for the neutrino emission are much higher than for the neutron star surface radiation by photons.